# How to make TypeScript work correctly with new `exports` and `main` field?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using Node.js version 16.10.0 with TypeScript 4.5.5. I am publishing a library with following configuration:

```
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
"exports": {
  "./package.json": "./package.json",
  "./*": "./dist/*"
},
"typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "*": [
      "./dist/*"
    ]
  }
},
```

When both `main` and `exports` are used, TypeScript fails to recognize the type configuration correctly. However, it works perfectly fine when I use either of:

- `main` + `types`
- `exports` + `typesVersion`

I can choose to not have `main` configuration but that breaks the Jest test runner as its resolve function doesn't work well with new package `exports`.

How to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to replicate the `main` path with an [entry point export](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports), i.e. an additional entry in the `exports` section mapped by `"."`. Using your example:

```json
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./package.json": "./package.json",
  "./*": "./dist/*"
},
"typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "*": [
      "./dist/*"
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.